# OpenGL polygon not rotating as expected

Tags: opengl

I have this little program that is supposed to rotate a square in 2D. When I give it fixed vertexes, it works fine. But when I try to put it in motion, the square just starts to flash and blink and not really resemble a square at all. Everything looks good to me, so I must be missing something. Can anyone see it?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <glut/glut.h>

#define DEG_TO_RAD 0.017453

GLsizei ww, wh;
GLfloat theta;

void display()
{
    //clear window
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //draw unit square polygon
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2f(sin(DEG_TO_RAD*theta), cos(DEG_TO_RAD*theta));
    glVertex2f(-sin(DEG_TO_RAD*theta), cos(DEG_TO_RAD*theta));
    glVertex2f(-sin(DEG_TO_RAD*theta), -cos(DEG_TO_RAD*theta));
    glVertex2f(sin(DEG_TO_RAD*theta), -cos(DEG_TO_RAD*theta));
//    glVertex2f(-0.5, -0.5);
//    glVertex2f(-0.5, 0.5);
//    glVertex2f(0.5, 0.5);
//    glVertex2f(0.5, -0.5);

    glEnd();

    //flush gl buffers
    glFlush();
}

void init() {
    //set color to black
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    //set fill color to white
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    //set up standard orthogonal view with clipping
    //box as cube of side2 centered at origin
    //this is default view and these statements could be removed
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
}

void myreshape(GLsizei w, GLsizei h) {
    //adjust clipping window
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    if (w<=h)
        gluOrtho2D(-2.0, 2.0, -2.0 * (GLfloat) h / (GLfloat) w, 2.0 * (GLfloat) h / (GLfloat) w);
    else
        gluOrtho2D(-2.0 * (GLfloat) w / (GLfloat) h, 2.0 * (GLfloat) w / (GLfloat) h, -2.0, 2.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    //adjust viewport
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    //set global size for use by drawing routine
    ww = w;
    wh = h;
}

void myidle() {
    theta += 2.0;
    if (theta > 360.0) theta -= 360.0;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    theta = 0.0;
    // initialize mode and open a window in upper-left corner of screen
    // window title is name of program (arg[0])
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);//Set the window size
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("rotating square");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    init();
    glutReshapeFunc(myreshape);
    glutIdleFunc(myidle);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not the proper way to rotate things in OpenGL - you have to re-define your vertices to rotate them if you do this. The proper way is to set your matrix mode to ModelView and use `glRotatef (...)`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm following along in the first chapters of a textbook, so I assume that the author is spoon feeding us for the moment to focus on basic concepts like vertexes, leaving out much of the native functionality for the time being. Aside from this code not being the proper way to do it, I'm still not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: See Nico's answer, I am pretty sure this will explain it all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vertex definitions just don't produce a square. Try the following:

```
glVertex2f(cos(DEG_TO_RAD*(theta + 135)), sin(DEG_TO_RAD*(theta + 135)));
glVertex2f(cos(DEG_TO_RAD*(theta + 45 )), sin(DEG_TO_RAD*(theta + 45 )));
glVertex2f(cos(DEG_TO_RAD*(theta - 45 )), sin(DEG_TO_RAD*(theta - 45 )));
glVertex2f(cos(DEG_TO_RAD*(theta - 135)), sin(DEG_TO_RAD*(theta - 135)));
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. As I mentioned above, this code comes from a textbook, so I'm pretty surprised that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The comment from Andon below your question is right. You should create the geometry (the vertices) only once and then rotate them by setting the matrix to ModelView and rotate with glRotatef(...). Recreating geometries on each render cycle is a wrong aproach.